# Where does this EditText come from in soft keyboard demo

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am building a custom keyboard from the sample code in the SDK I am trying to figure out where the view that contains the typed code comes from.

My goal here is to build a very basic keyboard that fits the specific look and feel of the existing application. I need to remove this view because it is not required.

Please see the attached screen shot for the view.

[image: Keyboard Screen Capture]

This application is used in a closed environment so I am not worried about the user selecting a different keyboard. In fact the stock Keyboard is a hazard since the navigation bar is disabled and can result in places that the users can't return from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done a simple search of the contents in all the files in your project after the string? Should find it that way if you search *.xml and *.java.

Comment: Yeah the "next" string comes from a definition but as far as I can tell it is being generated by the underlying KeyboardView class but it is hard to tell.